# What is the most elegant way to sort a list of objects in Java?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have the following java class:

```
public class Customer {
    private long id;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

And I also have a `List<Customer> customers`. What is the most elegant way to sort the list by `Customer.getId()` using a lambda expression?

Right now I have this code:

```
Comparator<Customer> customerComparator = (previousCustomer, nextCustomer) ->
        Long.compare(previousCustomer.getId(), nextCustomer.getId());

customers.sort(customerComparator);
```

But it feels clunky especially if I need to write a comparator for each different sort or for each different generic list. Could this be done with one line of code?

Comment: Inline the `customerComparator` variable ==> one line of code.

Comment: Would it not be better to implement `Comparable` in your `Customer` class and use `Collections.sort(customers)` if you don't have to use lambda

Comment: Please check the Method References [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html] trail

Answer (score 12):

I think you may be looking for the `Comparator.comparing...()` method:

```
customers.sort(comparingLong(Customer::getId))
```

Answer (score 10):

In Java 8 you can write on one line.

```
customers.sort((a, b) -> Long.compare(a.getId(), b.getId());
```

If you make the `Customer implements Comparable<Customer>` you can just do

```
customers.sort(Customer::compare);
```

or

```
customers.sort(null);
```

Comment: You can use `customers.sort(Customer::compare);` if the class `Customer` has a `compare` method. It doesn’t have to implement any specific interface for that.

Answer (score 4):

Sort the List using ***Lambda Expression***

```
customers.sort((c1, c2) -> Long.compare(c1.getId(),c2.getId()));
```